# How do i know what webcam driver to install?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, webcam, guvcview

I have a built in webcam for my laptop, I open Guvcveiw and it tells me the correct driver is not installed. I Don't know how this happens, or how to fix it, but my sister has the same exact computer as me, but it works fine. I have know idea what to do. (i have 14.04)

Comment: does it give you any extra info when you run guvcview from a terminal?

Comment: Use `dpkg -l` to list all the packages (including drivers) installed on your system. Use `dpkg -l` to list all the packages (including drivers) installed on your sister's system. Compare these files. This will show which packages your sister has installed that you don't.

Comment: @mchid all the extra info i get is "Unable to open device Please make sure the camera is connected and that the correct driver is installed" And obviously the camera is connected, it is built into the computer!

Comment: Sometimes it is disabled in BIOS. I believe it's called internal USB on some computers. Anyway, the driver is the video4linux or something similar to that I'll have to check.

Comment: "drivers" are usually not installed but included as modules of the linux kernel

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with guvcview on 14.04 except it was a segmentation fault. The fix for me was to clone the newest version using git.

First uninstall guvcview:

```
sudo apt-get purge guvcview
```

Then, install some dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep guvcview
```

Now, install git:

```
sudo apt-get install git automake build-essential
```

Clone the latest repo:

```
git clone http://git.code.sf.net/p/guvcview/git-master guvcview-git-master
```

Now, build and install:

```
cd guvc*
autoreconf -i -f
./configure
make
```

If there are no errors (ignore warnings), run the following command to install:

```
sudo make install
```

To run guvcview, run the following command:

```
guvcview &
```

To make a launcher for this application, run the following command:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/guvcview.desktop
```

Then, copy and paste the following into the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=guvcview
GenericName=GTK UVC video viewer
X-GNOME-FullName=GTK UVC video viewer
X-GNOME-FullName[cs]=Prohlížeč videa GTK UVC
X-GNOME-FullName[de]=UVC-Video-Betrachter in GTK
X-GNOME-FullName[en_AU]=GTK UVC video viewer
X-GNOME-FullName[es]=Reproductor video GTK UVC
X-GNOME-FullName[fr]=Logiciel GTK de visualisation de vidéo UVC
X-GNOME-FullName[it]=GTK UVC visualizzatore video
X-GNOME-FullName[lv]=GTK UVC video skatītājs
X-GNOME-FullName[nl]=GTK UVC videokijker
X-GNOME-FullName[pt]=Visualizador de vídeo GTK UVC
X-GNOME-FullName[pt_BR]=Visualizador de vídeo GTK UVC
X-GNOME-FullName[ru]=GTK UVC видео обозреватель
X-GNOME-FullName[si]=GTK UVC වීඩියෝ දකින්නා
X-GNOME-FullName[sr]=ГТК УВЦ видео приказивач
X-GNOME-FullName[tr]=GTK UVC video görüntüleyici
Comment=A video viewer and capturer for the linux uvc driver
TryExec=guvcview
Exec=guvcview
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/guvcview/guvcview.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Video;AudioVideo;
X-GNOME-Gettext-Domain=guvcview
StartupNotify=true
```

Finally, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

Please post any errors.

Comment: It told me that the command "make" didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out line beginning with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet...." and put the below instead. Afterwards, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1 acpi_enforce_resources=lax"

In case it doesn't work, run this command in a terminal:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo -1 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend'
```

Reboot.  Good luck.

Comment: It told me the first command didn't exist once i ran it in the termanal.

Comment: try sudo gkedit or sudo nano